# Background image height in responsive design css/ html

Tags: css

I have a background image. Its size is width 200px, height 120px. I'm redesigning the website to be responsive. If I get rid of height the image disappears altogether.

That's what I have:

```
height: 120px;
background: url('../img/index.png') no-repeat center;
-webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
-moz-transition: all ease 1s;
-o-transition: all ease 1s;
-ms-transition: all ease 1s;
transition: all ease 1s;
```

How can I get rid of height to make it responsive without losing the image?

Comment: <div class="indexContent grid_3 alpha">
      <div class="indexImg-1 grid_12">
      </div>
      <div class="indexText grid_12">
        <h2> Some Text</h2>
        <p>
          Other text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: would you be able to provide a jsfiddle of the code. So it would be easier since we do not know the styles you have given to the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're applying this styling to a `<div>`:

A `<div>` has no height of its own unless you set one. It will have only the height of its content, assuming the content isn't removed from the content flow by a `float` or other rule with similar effect.

If you remove the `height` rule, and the element has no content, it will shrink vertically to zero, and your background image will disappear.

Comment: You see I have a div inside a div. example:

Comment: example: <div class="head"><div class="head-Img"> </div>          <div class="head-text">   Assuming you're applying this styling to a
 has no height of its own unless you set one. It will have only the height of its content, assuming the content isn't removed from the content flow by a float or other rule with similar effect.
</div>      HEAD-IMG thats where the picture is. And it has a hover effect

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this:

```
    background-size: contain;
    background: url('img/index.png') no-repeat center;
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 200px;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking at the max-width and max-height properties?

Comment: That's not an answer - that's a comment.

Comment: Yes I tried setting max-width and max-height. No success.

The problem is that, that div is empty. There is nothing else in it other than background image. Reason why I did it like this is that I can have img:hover effect in css.

Comment: What is the html you're using?